# gunicorn booting workers on loop

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

i am trying to deploy a flask app on heroku but in logs i am getting this error continuosly in a loop , i am not using any docker/container

i am using `gunicorn==19.9.0`
and `python-3.7.7`

my procfile contains -> `web: gunicorn app:app`

```
2021-01-01T20:07:10.172164+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:10 +0000] [2363] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2363
2021-01-01T20:07:10.841592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:10 +0000] [2371] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2371
2021-01-01T20:07:11.478375+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:11 +0000] [2379] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2379
2021-01-01T20:07:11.677500+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:11 +0000] [2387] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2387
2021-01-01T20:07:12.595348+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:12 +0000] [2395] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2395
2021-01-01T20:07:12.815387+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:12 +0000] [2403] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2403
2021-01-01T20:07:13.193908+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:13 +0000] [2411] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2411
2021-01-01T20:07:13.862270+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:13 +0000] [2419] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2419
2021-01-01T20:07:15.142863+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:15 +0000] [2427] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2427
2021-01-01T20:07:15.254555+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:15 +0000] [2432] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2432
2021-01-01T20:07:16.884513+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:16 +0000] [2443] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2443
2021-01-01T20:07:17.027716+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:17 +0000] [2451] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2451
2021-01-01T20:07:18.413229+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:18 +0000] [2459] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2459
2021-01-01T20:07:18.844276+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:18 +0000] [2467] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2467
2021-01-01T20:07:19.835412+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:19 +0000] [2475] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2475
2021-01-01T20:07:20.329649+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-01 20:07:20 +0000] [2483] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2483
```